# Why session is saved to the database but doesn't get returned?

Tags: c#, reactjs, asp.net-core, session, asp.net-web-api

I'm using ASP.NET Core Web API backend and this is the code for the session api call:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("save-to-session")]
    public IActionResult SaveToSession(string id)
    {
        HttpContext.Session.SetString("user", id);
        return Content(id);
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("fetch-from-session")]
    public IActionResult FetchFromSession()
    {
        string name = HttpContext.Session.GetString("user");
        return Ok(name);
    }
```

Save works fine but when I call 'fetch-from-session' the name variable is always null,
and when I log in with my user I can see the session inside SSMS.
[Here you can see.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rTPiY.png)

This is my Startup file:

```
        services.AddDistributedSqlServerCache(options => {
            options.ConnectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("TestMEApiContext");
            options.SchemaName = "dbo";
            options.TableName = "Session";
        });

        services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
        services.AddSession(options => {
            options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(3000);
            options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
            options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
        });
```

I dont know it's a frontend or a backend issues so this is my React code when i'm calling it:

```
componentDidMount() {
    fetch(`https://localhost:44369/api/users/fetch-from-session`, { method: 'GET', credentials: "include", mode: 'cors' }).then(function (body) {
        return body.text();
    }).then((response) => {
        this.setState({ userId: response });
        fetch(`https://localhost:44369/api/users-tests/${response}`, {
            method: 'GET',
        })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(response => {
                this.setState({ usersTests: response });
            })
    });
}
```

[save-to-session headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qkSEG.png)

[fetch-from-session headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tRHDO.png)

Comment: Have you checked in the browser's DevTools (F12) that a cookie is actually being sent with the request to `fetch-from-session`?

Comment: Because `HttpContext.Session.GetString();` returns null there is nothing in the cookes.

Comment: Is a cookie ever being set in the browser? I.e. does the response from `save-to-session` contain a cookie?

Comment: Yes it contains, but when i try to fetch it, returns null.

Comment: Please add an example of the request and response headers+payloads for both endpoints

Comment: Edited the post and added a picture from the `save-to-session` and `fetch-from-session` api call headers

Comment: Was the browser window by any change closed and reopened between those two examples? In that case the cookie could have been deleted because of it.

Comment: No i didn't closed the browser :D Simply i didn't get the session from `HttpContext.Session.GetString`